# How to get expected write performance in XA transaction in Ehcache?

Tags: transactions, ehcache, xa

I cant say what the matter is but I am getting same write performance in XA and XA_strict modes.That is ten times more than normal write operation.
I am same configuration as in the Ehcache docs 2.9
And the read is also expensive then write,why?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify the question? Are you suffering from a decrease in performance with XA transaction?

Comment: yes @louis ,as the size of object grows the the performance in xa transaction becomes worse....for an object of 40 bytes the throughPut is 74 only and when I write the object of size around 280 ,the write throughput is 35.
Another issue is that the read is around 3 times slower when object size  is around 280.